# Semantic Tags vs. ARIA Role: Why one or the other?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I am aware than in many cases an HTML element does more than simple affect the page semantically, and the additional functionality make it a no-brainer choice. For example, although there is a [`textbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/textbox_role) ARIA role, it is nearly always preferable to just use an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element whenever possible.

However, for "semantic" HTML elements, I can't find any information indicating that they do anything more than supply a default ARIA role for the purpose of accessibility and provide some minor code readability enhancements. For example, the *only* purpose of the `<main>` element (as far as I can tell) seems to be a "shortcut" to avoid typing out a few extra characters `<div role="main">`, also resulting in a slight readability improvement.

So, is that tiny readability improvement really the *only* reason to use `<main>` over `<div role="main">`, or are there other reasons I might be missing? Is there any conceivable reason that I would ever want to prefer the latter?

Comment: I'm not sure I can give a good answer, but the only reasons (which are very few, and increasingly rare) to prefer a `div` with an ARIA `role` to a semantic element are [given in the W3C's "using ARIA" guide](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1). For your other question, afaik for "landmark" roles like `main` there's no other reason, but the difference becomes huge for interactive roles like `button` (or `textbox` as you say), where using the native element gives you focus and keyboard behaviour, all for free. I think you already know that - but don't forget these are "semantic" too!

Answer (score 1):

Semantically structuring your page with semantic HTML makes the contents machine-readable for the browser, browser extensions, search engines and other tools without extending their code to cover ARIA as well.

This is especially important for accessibility, as assistive technology are such tools, which might attach additional functionality to certain roles. Usually, these rely on the browser’s accessibility API, but there are several to cover for different platforms.

The browser’s read mode, for example, can easily extract contents from a `<main>`. Also handling role attributes makes coding it more difficult.

Also writing user stylesheets to improve accessibility is way easier if you don’t need to cover ARIA attributes.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, because it explains that browser and other tools might implement features which will recognize a `<main>` but might not also recognize a `<div role="main">`. This helps to address the _why_ of using the HTML element.

Comment: The browser Accessibility API exposes the same value if you use <main> or <div role="main">. Assistive technologies rely on the name, role and value expose by the API.

To verify, open DevTools of your browser, go to the Accessibility pane and inspect your code. The role will be the same.

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin great, glad it was helpful. Would you mind accepting this answer, or is another aspect unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

W3C has written a complete doc about using aria : [Using ARIA by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/)

The first rule of ARIA explains that you prioritize the native HTML element or attribute with the semantics and behavior already built in.

In your example, the  element is a native HTML element with an implicit main role. You can give a look to [the complete list of implicit roles of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance).

Comment: Downvoting this answer, because my question is regarding the _why_ of this, not just a statement saying "the official ARIA document says to do it, so do it".